# how to fix property does not exist on type 'Object' in ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have call the **API** for get the data and but I got error Property  **sellerDto**  does not exist on type **Object** in **ionic3** and I will try to declare the data as declared object but again same error occur how to fix this error?

```js
/*
  @Copyright Notice:
  @(#)
  @Type: TS 
  @For:  create-accont.html.
  @Description : userLoggedInSuccess for create the user account 1st in the GCP 
 */
 public userData       : any = {};
userLoggedInSuccess(userObject) {
    //Enable the loader after call the FB function
    var self = this;
    //Declare the local variable
    self.url                  = "";
    self.API_HOST             = "";
    self.paramData                 = "";
    let userTypeKeyId = userObject.uid;

    let url = self.API_HOST + "/api/login/dto";
    let paramData  = "userTypeKeyId=" + userTypeKeyId;

    let headers =  {
      headers: new  HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
    };

    //Pass the data into the API for check email is exist in the API or not
    self.http.post(url, paramData, headers).subscribe(data => {
      this.userData = data;
      if(this.userData.isLoggedIn) {
          //Here we will set the user Detail into the local-storage
          if(this.userData.userType == "seller" && this.userData.sellerDto == undefined){
            self.localStorage.set("defaultLanguage",    data.sellerDto.userTypeDto.defaultLanguage);
          }
        } else {
          console.log("user is no valid");
        }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try typing the variable `data :any`

```
 self.http.post(url, paramData, headers).subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.userData = data;
      if(this.userData.isLoggedIn) {
          //Here we will set the user Detail into the local-storage
          if(this.userData.userType == "seller" && this.userData.sellerDto == undefined){
            self.localStorage.set("defaultLanguage",    data.sellerDto.userTypeDto.defaultLanguage);
          }
        } else {
          console.log("user is no valid");
        }
  });
```

Comment: thank you its working for me but tell m sir why we pass (data:any) ?

Comment: Because your error comes from typescript complaining about the type of  data which is object. Object doesn't have an attribute called sellerDto. Instead we told typescript that data is in fact type any. In the answer did help you please accept it to help others